# Select condition for value of two cells and color the row

Tags: vba, if-statement

In the code below, if code finds "0" in a cell of column G, few cells in that row are colored, I would like to have these cells colored only if value "0" is found in Column G and Column H in the same row, how can this be done?

```
With Worksheets("Sheet3")


    For Each cell In Range("G2:G" & LastRow)
        If cell.Value = "0" Then
            cell.Range("A1:F1").Offset(0, -5).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
        ElseIf cell.Value = "1" Then
            cell.Range("A1:F1").Offset(0, -5).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        Else
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Conditional formatting: `=AND($G1 = 0,$H1 = 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified like this to color the cells from A to F of a given row having 0 in G and H:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    For Each cell In Range("G2:G" & LastRow)
        currentRow = cell.Row '<-- change
        If cell.Value = 0 And Range("H" & currentRow).Value = 0 Then '<-- change
            Range("A" & currentRow & ":F" & currentRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 20 '<-- coloring from A to F of the same row
        End If
    Next cell '<-- change
End With
```

Comment: after testing your code I just noticed that code treats empty cell like it would have value "0" in it, so highlights also combination of cell with value "0" in the and empty cell next to it....

Comment: Yes, because if the cell is empty it is seen as "zero". You can just add a further test And cell.Value <> "" to avoid that.